# Unable to select from dropdown using "Select", getting element is not visible exception

Tags: java, selenium, select

I am trying to select some values from a dropdown and have tries all the options : selectByIndex, selectByVisibleText, selectByValue but I am unable to select value on the page; tried different waits also but still getting get the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Element is not visible (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace 
information)
Command duration or timeout: 42 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta3', revision: 'c7b525d',  os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, 
appBuildId=20160726073904, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, 
specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=48.0, 
platformVersion=10.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, 
browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, 
platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
Session ID: 83d79d14-527d-4a8e-a05e-01671d7b73f3
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:631)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:284)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.setSelected(Select.java:324)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByValue(Select.java:201)
at accessingForms.FormElements.main(FormElements.java:39)
```

Below is the snippet of my code, firefox version 48

```
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userName")));     
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("here")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("country")));
    System.out.println("wait statement executed");
 Select CountryDrpDwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
    System.out.println("found the drop down");      
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    CountryDrpDwn.selectByValue("3");
    System.out.println("Selected by value mofo");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    CountryDrpDwn.selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA ");
    System.out.println("Antarctica Selected");
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Can you share some `html` for the dropdown? There is a chance this dropdown might not be one that works well with the selenium `Select`.

Comment: Could you add implicit wait and try

Comment: Why are you using  **3.0.0-beta3** .Move to latest version atleast

Comment: @mrfreester http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php please check the html on this URL for 'country'

Comment: @Madhan code was working earlier.. I am looking for specific reason why not working now

Comment: I tried your code with chrome 59,ie 11 and firefox 54. Using Selenium 3.4 All working fine..